# trying to save my app user's desired data to this table

Tags: javascript, function, html-table

(this is on electron.js with no jquery or external libraries)

I currently have a form where the user writes in 'name', 'pnum(meaning phone number)' & 'age' into a form which is then submitted. On submit, I have a function named 'addTableRow();' that is supposed to add this to the table which it does do but immediately after the row appears, the row vanishes. Of course, this means that I need to save the table data (which is name.value, pnum.value & age.value) to a JSON file which can then be called & loaded to re-display this data on the table.

My issue is that the methods of saving this data & parsing it that I have tried do not work ( I am somewhat new to this so maybe it is an obvious mistake ) My current method is shown here:

```
const addTableRow = () => {

  const name = document.querySelector("#name");
  const pnum = document.querySelector("#pnum");
  const age = document.querySelector("#age");

  let table = document.querySelector("#clientTable");

  let row = table.insertRow(-1);

  let c1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let c2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let c3 = row.insertCell(2);

  c1.innerHTML = name.value;
  c2.innerHTML = pnum.value;
  c3.innerHTML = age.value;
  
  //the object array that I'm converting to JSON
  const clientTable = {
    clientTable: [
      {
        name: c1.innerHTML,
        pnum: c2.innerHTML,
        age: c3.innerHTML
      }
    ]
  }

  const tableRowIn = JSON.stringify('clientTable');
  
  // the method for displaying the data is called
  displayTableData();

  table.appendChild(row);
}

// the table template
const createNewRow = (clientTable) => {
  return `<tr>
  <td>${clientTable.name}</td>
  <td>${clientTable.pnum}</td>
  <td>${clientTable.age}</td>
  </tr>`
}

//this is just to delete a row & isn't relevant to my question
const deleteTableRow = () => {
  document.querySelector('#clientTable').deleteRow(1);
}

// the method to display the data
const displayTableData = () => {
  JSON.parse('clientTable').then(createNewRow())
}
```

As you would expect, I've tried many ways of storing this ( again, sorry if the answer is obvious ) including some other things people have showed me but of course this is an electron desktop app so local browser storage doesn't work meaning I'm left with JSON stringify & parse which I've tried to implement here.

If anyone can show me where I'm going wrong or maybe show me a tutorial that covers this ( most online tutorials about this are either low-effort or don't cover this ) that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why is the newly added row disappearing? Your `displayTableData` function is in a different scope than the `addTableRow` function - have you considered passing in the object as a parameter?

Comment: @nimrod I am not sure why the row disappears I can't see any refresh that might affect it. also, the reason the row is added is due to a refresh so e.preventDefault(); wouldn't affect it.
Thanks for the response by the way!
did you mean something like this?
```
const displayTableData = (clientTable) => {
  JSON.parse(clientTable).then(createNewRow())
}
```
Using this, the program still won't save the data

Comment: Maybe is should call the displayTableData(); function whenever #clTab (meaning clients tab) is opened so that it appears on demand. The problem though, is that the function createNewRow(); doesn't seem to work. something like 
```
const displayTableData = (clientTable) => {
  if (document.querySelector('#clTab') === t.classList('active')) {
    JSON.parse(clientTable).then(createNewRow())
  }
}
```
might work to call displayTableData(); when needed